# How to add validation errors in the validation collection asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Inside my controller's action I have the following code:

```
public ActionResult GridAction(string id)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) 
    {
        // add errors to the errors collection and then return the view saying that you cannot select the dropdownlist value with the "Please Select" option
    }

    return View(); 
}
```

UPDATE:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
{
    // add error 
    ModelState.AddModelError("GridActionDropDownList", "Please select an option");
    return RedirectToAction("Orders"); 
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is my updated code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedGridAction, Model.GridActions,"Please Select") 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedGridAction)
```

The Model looks like the following:

```
public class MyInvoicesViewModel
{

    private List<SelectListItem> _gridActions;

    public int CurrentGridAction { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an option")]
    public string SelectedGridAction { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> GridActions
    {
        get
        {
            _gridActions = new List<SelectListItem>();
            _gridActions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Export to Excel", Value = "1" });

            return _gridActions;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult GridAction(string id)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        // add error 
        ModelState.AddModelError("SelectedGridAction", "Please select an option");
        return RedirectToAction("Orders"); 
    }

    return View(); 
}
```

Nothing happens! I am totally lost on this one!

UPDATE 3:

I am now using the following code but still the validation is not firing:

```
public ActionResult GridAction(string id)
{
    var myViewModel= new MyViewModel();
    myViewModel.SelectedGridAction = id; // id is passed as null           

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Orders");
    }
```

UPDATE 4:

```
$("#linkGridAction").click(function () {
    alert('link grid action clicked'); 

    $.get('GridAction/', { SelectedGridAction: $("#SelectedGridAction").val() }, function (result) {
        alert('success');
    });
});
```

And the Controller looks like the following:

```
// OrderViewModel has a property called SelectedGridAction. 
public ActionResult GridAction(OrderViewModel orderViewModel)
{
    return View(); 
}
```

UPDATE 5: Validation is not firing:

```
public ActionResult GridAction(OrderViewModel orderViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Orders", orderViewModel); 
    }
    return View(); 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult GridAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // the model is valid, the user has selected an id => use it
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
    return View();
}
```

---

UPDATE:

After the hundreds of comments on my answer I feel in the necessity to provide a full working example:

As usual start with a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string SelectedItemId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items 
    {
        get
        {
            // Dummy data
            return new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                .Select(i => new SelectListItem 
                {
                    Value = i.ToString(),
                    Text = "item " + i 
                }), 
            "Value", "Text");
        }
    }
}
```

Then a controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // The user didn't select any value => redisplay the form
            return View(model);
        }
        // TODO: do something with model.SelectedItemId
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
}
```

and finally the view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedItemId, 
        Model.Items, 
        "-- Select Item --"
    ) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedItemId) %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a value when the user selects the "Please Select" option.

Comment: @johndoe, there shouldn't be. If you use the following helper method: `<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, Model.Items, "-- please select --") %>` to generate your dropdown no value will be sent and validation will automatically work. Also it makes more sense to send empty string when the user hasn't selected anything rather than some dummy value.

Comment: I should also add that the page is not being submitted (no submit button) but an action is invoked through a link and that is why the validation is not being fired!

Comment: @johndoe, from validation standpoint it doesn't matter how the request is sent. The important thing is to send an `id` parameter along the request. If this parameter is empty validation will fail => it is as if the user hasn't selected any value in the dropdown.

Comment: @johndoe, didn't you read my answer? I suggested you passing the model as action argument and not just id. So try: `public ActionResult GridAction(MyInvoicesViewModel model)` and inside this action you don't need to manually check whether the id is null or empty. This will be automatically handled by the model binder because your model has the SelectedGridAction property decorated with the Required attribute. Also in case of error you should not redirect, you should return the same view if you want validation errors to be shown: `if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();`

Comment: But if I am invoking the action using a link how can I send the ViewModel as an action argument. Usually, ViewModel gets populated when the user submits the view using the submit button.

Comment: @johndoe, it depends what you want to send. If you want to send some value that the user could change like for example a dropdown value selection you cannot use a normal action link. You need to use javascript to read the value and either redirect with window.location or send an AJAX request. If you want to send a static value which was known at the moment the view was rendered you could do this: `<%=Html.ActionLink("foo", "fooAction", new { id = "some static value" }) %>`.

Comment: In UPDATE 3 I am getting the string from the action and then assigning to the ViewModel and then validating the ViewModel but for some reason it is always returning TRUE.

Comment: @johndoe, in order for validation to work you need to pass `MyViewModel` as argument to your action. By doing `myViewModel.SelectedGridAction = id` absolutely no validation is triggered and your model will always be valid.

Comment: Can I use the ModelState.AddModelError approach then?

Comment: Yes, but this approach makes you write unnecessary code in your action. You should write an if and manually add the error message whereas if you follow my recommendation your controller action will be very simple and the validation will be automatically handled thanks to the Required attribute.

Comment: Yes, but passing ViewModel as parameter using the DropDownList whose values are changing is hard and I have no idea where to begin. I know when the user submits the form all the values are posted to the action but using actionlink and dropdownlist makes it hard!

Comment: @johndoe, whether you use a viewmodel containing the Id property as action argument or simply the id is absolutely the same. It's just that in the first case validation will work. As far as the actionlink is concerned you could use AJAX.

Comment: So If I use AJAX. I would just send the parameters in JSON format and it will be mapped correctly to the appropriate properties of the VieWModel?

Comment: @johndoe, you don't need to send them as JSON. You could send them as normal parameters. For example: `$.get('/someaction', { param1: 'value 1', param2: 'value 2' }, function(result) { alert('success'); });`

Comment: @johndoe, in ASP.NET MVC 3 there is a model binder capable of receiving and parsing JSON requests but in previous versions you will have to implement it yourself. As far as sending JSON to the response there's no problem at all.

Comment: I just tried the AJAX approach sending individual parameters but inside the controller the SelectedGridAction is always null even though I can see it being passed in FireBug.

Comment: @johndoe, you will have to provide more details about how you are doing this.

Comment: Sorry for that! Just posted UPDATE 4

Comment: @johndoe, just after the call to `$.get()` add a `return false;` in order to cancel the default action.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Darin!! Sorry for all the trouble! First day with ASP.NET MVC framework :(

Comment: Ahh crap! Now the validation is not firing!!

Comment: @johndoe, it is firing, inside your controller action the modelstate is not valid but because you are sending an AJAX request the DOM is not updated and you don't see the validation errors. You might need to use a partial view and return this partial view from the controller action and then in the success callback of your AJAX request inject this view into the DOM.

Comment: can I just return anonymous object from PartialView like: return PartialView(new {ErrorMessage = "Error"}); How should I consume this on html side!

Comment: @johndoe, no. A partial view needs a corresponding .ASCX file which will contain the HTML fragment that you want to update during your AJAX call.

Comment: That is simple too much work to just to display a message to the user that "Please select an option from the list".

Comment: @johndoe, then use a simple `<form>`.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean use a simple <form>?

Comment: Thanks! yeah I could do that Thanks!

Answer (score 60):

Use `ModelState.AddModelError()`

```
ModelState.AddModelError("MyDropDownListKey", "Please Select");
```

and output to the view like this:

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("MyDropDownListKey") %>
```

Comment: +1 for direct & short answer "Use `ModelState.AddModelError()`".

Comment: Where do I get the Key from?  I ahve the following: `<span class="field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientID,"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </span>` what would be the key?

Comment: If you know what property you're working with you can rely on DataAnnotations or try adding an error for "ClientID"

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your update #3, I suspect thats because you are actually assigning the value, its just an empty string (Required is checking for null).

You want to do have this:

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
```

Your best bet though would be to perform custom validation (you will likely want to verify the key is in the list, etc)

Edit: fixed typo in the code - forgot closing ")"