# When using MVC code first with data annotations how do you include html markup in the display name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first, razor-2

I am converting a paper form into a MVC 4 web form.  I have questions that are a paragraph worth of text that include superscript numbers that link to footnotes.  This is what I am trying to do:

```
public class PaperFormModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Full paragraph of question text copied straight 
         off of the paper form<a href="#footnote1"><sup>footnote 1</sup></a> 
         and it needs to include the properly formatted superscript 
         and/or a link to the footnote text.")]
    public string Question1 { get; set; }

    // more properties go here ...
}
```

After creating the model I generated the controller and related views.  Everything works except the html markup in the display name is converted into html encoded text (i.e. &lt;sup&gt;1&lt;/sup&gt;).  The code in the view.cshtml used to display the property is just the automatically generated code:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question1)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Question1)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question1)
</div>
```

I am trying to figure out how to get the html markup for the footnotes to work properly or is my approach somehow wrong and I should be doing it a different way?  This is my first MVC project and I am coming from an asp.net background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try to move your HTML text to resources and apply for your model the next code:

```
public class PaperFormModel
{    
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(PaperFormModelResources), Name = "Question1FieldName")]
    public string Question1 { get; set; }

    // more properties go here ...
}
```

**To create resource file:**
- Create `Resources` folder in your solution if it does not exist.
- `Right click on this folder in solution explorer -> Add -> Resource file` or `... -> Add -> New item` and select `resource file`
- Name this file `PaperFormModelResources`
- Add new entry with name `Question1FieldName` and with value `Full paragraph of question text copied straight off of the paper form<a href="#footnote1"><sup>footnote 1</sup></a> and it needs to include the properly formatted superscript and/or a link to the footnote text.` using resource manager.

**EDITS:**
If, as result, your html markup is not displayed correctly (it is just displayed as plain text) you can use the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999130/how-can-i-render-html-in-validation-message-in-asp-net-mvc) that is:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question1).ToHtmlString))
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Question1)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question1)
</div>
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: If you put the '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility...' part into its own answer I will mark that as the answer.

Comment: @Bakanekobrain, I've already applied those changes in my answer to fit your question: `@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question1).ToHtmlString))`

Comment: ToHtmlString is a method call, so it needs parentheses.